# Display of ListView include in an other ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have a problem and I can't solve it. I would like to create poll application. I Create 2 classes : 
- Poll which contain user's name, the question and an ArrayList of Choice
- Choice contain the choice and its id.

I would like to display on the home page a list of questions (ArrayList) with the differents choices. I managed to display this list but I have a problem with  ArrayList of the class Poll because only the first item is display but I want to display all the list of choice.

POLL CLASS

```
public class Poll{
    String question;
    String forename;
    ArrayList<Choice> list_choices;


    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }
    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    public ArrayList<Choice> getListChoice() {
        return list_choices;
    }
    public void setListChoice(ArrayList<Choice> list_choices) {
        this.list_choices = list_choices;
    }
}
```

CHOICE CLASS

```
public class Choice {
    int id;
    String choice;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getChoice() {
        return choice;
    }
    public void setChoice(String choice) {
        this.choice = choice;
    }

}
```

Adapter for Poll

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<Poll> listPolls;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Poll> listPolls) {
        this.listPolls = listPolls;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listPolls.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return listPolls.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (arg1==null)
        {
            arg1= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ForenameView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.forename);
            holder.QuestionView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.question);
            holder.ChoiceView = (ListView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.choice);
               //tagguer notre objet pour pouvoir le récupérer à la prochaine mise à jour graphique.
            arg1.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
        }


        holder.ForenameView.setText(listPolls.get(arg0).getForename());
        holder.QuestionView.setText(listPolls.get(arg0).getQuestion());
        holder.ChoiceView.setAdapter(new CustomListChoiceAdapter(context, listPolls.get(arg0).getListChoice()));
        return arg1;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView ForenameView;
        TextView QuestionView;
        ListView ChoiceView;
    }
}
```

Adapter for choice

```
public class CustomListChoiceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<Choice> listChoices;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomListChoiceAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Choice> listChoices) {
        this.listChoices = listChoices;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listChoices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return listChoices.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (arg1==null)
        {
            arg1= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_choice, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ChoiceView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.choice_text);
            //holder.IdView = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.question);
            //tagguer notre objet pour pouvoir le récupérer à la prochaine mise à jour graphique.
            arg1.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) arg1.getTag();
        }
        holder.ChoiceView.setText(listChoices.get(arg0).getChoice());
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        //holder.IdView.setText(listChoices.get(arg0).getId());

        return arg1;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView ChoiceView;
        //TextView IdView;
    }
}
```

XML Home page

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
            >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML Poll List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/forename"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:textColor="@color/blue"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="TextView" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/choice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="#000000"
                >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

XML Choice List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/choice_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textColor="@color/pink"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity which display ArrayList

```
public class debug extends Activity {
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.debugg);
        //Récuperation de ListView crée

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        ArrayList<Choice> list_choice = new ArrayList<Choice>();
        Choice choix = new Choice();
        choix.setChoice("choix 1");
        list_choice.add(choix);
        choix = new Choice();
        choix.setChoice("choix 2");
        list_choice.add(choix);


        ArrayList<Poll> resultats = new ArrayList<Poll>();
        Poll newsData = new Poll();
        newsData.setListChoice(list_choice);
        newsData.setForename("Paul");
        newsData.setQuestion("Question 1");
        resultats.add(newsData);
        newsData = new Poll();
        newsData.setListChoice(list_choice);
        newsData.setForename("Laetitia");
        newsData.setQuestion("Question 2");
        resultats.add(newsData);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, resultats));
    }

}
```

Comment: English here please.

Comment: you either need to use section, an expandablelistadapter, or to change your design. listview in a listview just won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, the one and origin solution is:

Set your parent `ListView` item `WRAP_CONTENT` height. Next, set fixed height of your included `ListView` item. Then in `getView()` method set the height of your included `ListView` the height equals to `parent_array_list.size() * child_list_view_item_height`. It might be help you.

Code example:

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (listPolls.size() * TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, child_list_view_item_height, displayMetrics)));
holder.ChoiceView.setLayoutParams(params);
```